# Cosmosdb partision

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmos db container with below fields (id,name,Category,Type). I am new to cosmos db and playing around with it. I will be doing search
using ID, Name. What will be the better way to create a partition key?

Answer (score 0):

While deciding partition key you need to choose a property/attribute that will not change. Cosmos db does not allow you to change it.

As you mentioned you mostly will be searching around id and name, I would suggest you to keep your partition key on Id as name could change. You can also put Category as a partition key and all similar objects will be grouped together in physical/logical partitions based on it. You can read through this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067692/azure-cosmos-db-understanding-partition-key) which has very apt description on your requirements.

Also, you can create a synthetic key based on combination of both these id and name properties ([Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys)), but this would not make much sense in this case.